# SSSD LDAP CONFIGURATION

Tags: centos, redhat, ldap, openldap, sssd

I am trying to configure ldap on port 636 on a redhat server. Right now, when I try the following command :

```
 netstat -antup | grep -i 636
```

I get

```
tcp        0    132 IP_ADDRESS_1:40670     XX.XX.XX.XX:636      ESTABLISHED XXXXX/sssd_be
```

Is there a way to change IP_ADDRESS_1 to another IP address ? I changed the sssd.conf [nss] and added override_homedir = IP_ADDRESS_NEW but the netstat still shows the sssd_be is bound to IP_ADDRESS_1.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: `override_homedir ` have different purpose and I do not think this will help you

Comment: @RomeoNinov what can I do then to make it work?